# Concatenate video files and add a watermark

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

I have two different sets of [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) commands working that I would like to try to combine.

The first command is a basic "concat" command:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file01.mpg|file02.mpg|file03.mpg" -c copy -target pal-dvd newfile.mpg
```

The second adds a watermark:

```
ffmpeg -i newfile.mpg -i full_page_watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" -target pal-dvd newfilewatermark.mpg
```

***Question***:

How would I combine these two commands? Or is it necessary to first create the intermediate file as I am presently doing?

Comment: A similar question was asked recently. Use the `concat` and `overlay` filters in a `filter_complex` filtergraph. You may need to add filters to scale your videos if they have different frame sizes. If you can't get it to work, please update your question with the command you're trying and the full command line output, too. Then leave me a comment.

Comment: @slhck, thanks for the link. That certainly solves my problem. Pretty new to this video work, so perhaps I haven't figured out the correct terms to search for.